# How does Om render list objects?

Tags: clojurescript, om

I'm struggling with understanding how om uses apply to render list items, as shown in the example below taken from the Om tutorial page.

```
(om/root
  (fn [data owner]
    (om/component 
      (apply dom/ul nil
        (map (fn [text] (dom/li nil text)) (:list data)))))
  app-state
  {:target (. js/document (getElementById "app0"))})
```

My understanding of apply is that it takes a function and a list of items and apply that function to the list. But in this example that understanding would translate to applying `dom/ul` to `nil`.

The things I don't understand are:

- Why am I applying `dom/ul` to a list, I don't want to create `ul` elements, I want to create `li` elements?
- How does apply handle all the parameters sent in this example?

Answer (score 2):

[`dom/ul`](https://github.com/omcljs/om/blob/master/src/om/dom.clj#L140) is a function that produces a React component that will render the corresponding DOM element. The first argument to `dom/ul` specifies the attributes that you want the DOM element to have. For example, if you wanted `dom/ul` to have the class attribute set to "main", you would do the following:

```
  (apply dom/ul #js {:className "main"}
    (map (fn [text] (dom/li nil text)) (:list data)))
```

Passing nil to the first argument of `dom/ul` simply sets no DOM attributes.

Clojure [`apply`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/apply) invokes `dom/ul` by prepending all arguments (after the `dom/ul` argument) to the final list (produced by map) argument and passing the result as arguments to `dom/ul`.

As an example, let's say data had the following value:

```
["Apple" "Bird"]
```

then `dom/ul` in your example would eventually be invoked as:

```
(dom/ul nil
    (dom/li nil "Apple")
    (dom/li nil "Bird"))
```

which would result in the following HTML being rendered :

```
<ul>
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Bird</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

When I first started learning Om, this took me a while to understand. The key thing to remember is that every `om.dom` function takes a JS map of attributes as it's first parameter, and then any number of `om.dom` arguments afterwards. What you might be expecting as I did, was that `om.dom` functions would take attributes and a vector of dom elements. Once this clicked, a lot of Om's design made more sense to me.

Clojure's apply "unwraps" a collection and passes the elements of the collection as arguments to the function being applied. So the intermediate steps of our computation are:

```
(apply dom/ul nil
    (map (fn [text] (dom/li nil text)) (:list data)))
```

then

```
(apply dom/ul nil
    '((dom/li nil "Hi") (dom/li nil "there")))
```

then

```
(dom/ul nil
    (dom/li nil "Hi") (dom/li nil "there"))
```

Without the apply, we wouldn't be passing the right arguments to `dom/ul`. You will also see apply being used with om/build-all which returns a collection like `map`.

One more example to extend this, if we wanted to put two `dom/ul`'s inside a `dom/p`, it would look like this in expanded form:

```
(dom/p nil
    (dom/ul nil (dom/li nil "Hi") (dom/li nil "there"))
    (dom/ul nil (dom/li nil "Next") (dom/li nil "list")))
```